# Subtracting values from a column on a specific condition and getting a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataset with two columns, I would like to do some operations on a particular column and get a new dataframe altogether. Consider this as my dataset:

```
A   B
1   01
1   56
1   89
1   108
2   23
2   36
2   89
3   13
4   45
```

I would like to perform two operations on the column B and create a dataframe with these 2 columns. 1st Column would be the Highest number for 1 ie - 108 subtracted by its least - 1 (108 - 1), for 2 - (89 - 23) and if its a single instance it should directly be 0. 2nd Column would be a specific number, assume it to be 125 subtracted by the very first instance of value in A ie ( 125 - 1), (125 - 23), (125 - 13)... We should get something like this:

```
A   C     D
1   107  124
2   66   102
3   0    112
4   0    80
```

I was thinking of using .loc to find the specific position of the value and then subtract it, How should I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) by `first` and custom function with lambda, then rename columns and substract `125` with `D` :

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg([lambda x: x.max() - x.min(), 'first']) \
                         .rename(columns={'first':'D','<lambda>':'C'}) \
                         .assign(D= lambda x: 125 - x['D']) \
                         .reset_index() 
print (df)
   A    C    D
0  1  107  124
1  2   66  102
2  3    0  112
3  4    0   80
```

`rename` is necessary, because [deprecate groupby agg with a dictionary when renaming](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#deprecate-groupby-agg-with-a-dictionary-when-renaming).

Another solution:

```
df = df.groupby('A')['B'].agg(['min','max', 'first']) \
                         .rename(columns={'first':'D','min':'C'}) \
                         .assign(D=lambda x: 125 - x['D'], C=lambda x: x['max'] - x['C']) \
                         .drop('max', axis=1) \
                         .reset_index() 
print (df)
   A    C    D
0  1  107  124
1  2   66  102
2  3    0  112
3  4    0   80
```

Comment: You may want to check OP's output for `D`.

Comment: There is some problem with output of D, can you please check again @jezrael

Comment: Yes, first solution was bad, but now it is correct. sorry for it.

Comment: I am still getting the same output for D, with the changed solution, can you please check again @jezrael

Comment: Not some typo? Because I get same output as need in question.

Comment: Still some problem? With your real data or with samples?

Answer (score 0):

```
u = df.groupby('A').agg(['max', 'min', 'first'])
u.columns = 'max', 'min', 'first'
u['C'] = u['max'] - u['min']
u['D'] = 125 - u['first']
del u['min']
del u['max']
del u['first']
u.reset_index()
#   A    C    D
#0  1  107  124
#1  2   66  102
#2  3    0  112
#3  4    0   80
```

Comment: maybe drop should be nicer like 3 times del ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could

```
In [1494]: df.groupby('A', as_index=False).B.agg(
              {'C': lambda x: x.max() - x.min(), 'D': lambda x: 125-x.iloc[0]})
Out[1494]:
   A    C    D
0  1  107  124
1  2   66  102
2  3    0  112
3  4    0   80
```